# Are Tableau dashboards, hosted on Tableau Server, downloadable by viewers?

Tags: tableau-api

If you download a Tableau Public dashboard, you'll get access to the datasets that where use to make it.

I believe it is the same for Tableau Desktop dashboards.

Which leads me to : are Tableau Desktop documents, stored on a Tableau Server, downloadable by anyone with access to that link ?

I would like to publish a Tableau Desktop dashboard on a Tableau Server so I can put it on a website yet I don't want the viewers to be able to download the dashboard. Knowing this will likely determine whether or not I buy Tableau Server.

Comment: When publishibg you can set up permissions for particular users. You can also depricate download workbook/datasouce actions
Here is more https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/permissions.htm

Comment: Thanks Mikhail-t. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes, people who have access to download (**which you set in the user or group permissions**) will be able to see whatever data it is connected to. If it is connected to a database such as SQL the user would be prompted to enter credentials that are allowed to connect to that database. If the data is in the form of an excel document then it would just be available with the download.

It sounds to me all you really need is to just limit the users from having download access, which is changed in the user/group settings. Just let them "view only".

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer above:

- Not only in Tableau Server can you restrict users from downloading your data, also in Tableau Public. Under 'Edit details' of your dashboard, you will find a checkbox for "Allow workbook and its data to be downloaded by others". If you uncheck this, viewers will not be able to download the workbook or it's underlying data.
- To add to your real intentions with this question: As far as I understand your question, you want to use Tableau Server to present you data on a website. Is this website meant for everyone to be accessible without signing in to Tableau Server? If so, then this will not be possible with a regular Tableau Server license, only with the (very expensive) core license. 
  See the explanation on Tableau's website about embedded views: [Embedded views](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed.html)

Comment: I see. That's an interesting point. I'll dive a bit deeper in this. Thanks for pointing this out.